# How to load xib file with attached view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am using a xib file as a back view in coverflow component . and it is seeing nicely .

The code for loading a xib file is :

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestMine" owner:nil options:nil];
        backView = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now I want to attach a view controller with this xib without changing the current code .

How can I do so ?

I am getting the error : `Exception :*** -[UIViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5891120`

Tell me if more details need to answer the question .

Thanks .
[image]

Comment: Have you attached the controller to the view in Interface Builder?

Comment: Should I add a controller from library and then connect the view in IB  or else ?

Answer (score 19):

I don't exactly understand your question. It seems like you want to instantiate a view controller with this xib as the view?

You can do that like this:

```
[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestMine" bundle:nil];
```

You should subclass UIViewController in order to hook up IBOutlets and IBActions.
Make sure you set the view controller as the file's owner and hook up it's outlets.

Comment: Sorry that you misunderstood the question . The question is I am just loading the nib with the above code and I have shown in the picture the viewcontroller in the xib file . so I am asking that whether the viewcontroller in that xib can handle that view with just above code of loading the xib file from mainBundle