# Where to add a loading view in an iphone/ipad app?

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a view made in Interface Builder and I want to show it every time I need time to get some data from a server. I need to add it on top of everything, I mean, modals can be presenting when this view is visible, and this view has to be always on top.

Any help?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your view from "nib" and then add it to your window/view as a subview like here: [How to load an XIB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448207/how-to-load-an-xib) or here: [How to load xib file with attached view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825442/how-to-load-xib-file-with-attached-view-controller)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I tried to add the view to the app's window, but when I present modals while this view is present, I get and UI flick and that's what I'm trying to avoid, and the other thing is that the loading view didn't rotate when the device rotates.Is there another way? Thanks!!!